# Recursive function problem after changing return array into mysql command - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, combinations

I have a function which gives me every possible combinations, given the sum of values ($x_entrees) and the length of the array ($n_valeurs).

```
    function distributions_possibles($n_valeurs, $x_entrees, $combi_presences = array()) {
        if ($n_valeurs == 1) {
            $combi_presences[] = $x_entrees;
            return array($combi_presences);
        }

        $combinaisons = array();

        // on fait appel à une fonction récursive pour générer les distributions
        for ($tiroir = 0; $tiroir <= $x_entrees; $tiroir++) {
            $combinaisons = array_merge($combinaisons, distributions_possibles(
                $n_valeurs - 1,
                $x_entrees - $tiroir,
                array_merge($combi_presences, array($tiroir))));
        }
        return $combinaisons;
    }

distributions_possibles(4,4);

// Output :
[0,0,0,4]
[0,0,1,3]
[0,0,2,2]
[0,0,3,1]
[0,0,4,0]
...
```

I tried to change it to send every combination directly into a mysql database.

```
function distributions_possibles($n_valeurs, $x_entrees, $combi_presences = array()) {
    if ($n_valeurs == 1) {
        $combi_presences[] = $x_entrees;
        return array($combi_presences);
    }

    $combinaisons = array();

    for ($tiroir = 0; $tiroir <= $x_entrees; $tiroir++) {
        $combinaisons = distributions_possibles(
            $n_valeurs - 1,
            $x_entrees - $tiroir,
            array_merge($combi_presences, array($tiroir)));
        global $bdd;
        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO distributions (ID, distribution, repartition, nb_solutions, reduction) VALUES (NULL, "'.implode($combinaisons[0]).'", 0, 0, 0)');
        $req->execute();
    }
    return $combinaisons;
}
```

The combinations are sent in the database but some duplicatas appeared, for example :

```
distributions_possibles(4,4);

// Output
[0,0,0,4]
[0,0,1,3]
[0,0,2,2]
[0,0,3,1]
[0,0,4,0]
[0,0,4,0]
...
```

I don't understand why some combinations are created two times or more, and I would like to make disappear the duplicatas, do you have any ideas ?

EDIT : I made some update in my function and it seems to have deleted the duplicatas, but it is not pretty...

```
$x=0;
$distri[-1] = 0;
function distributions_possibles2($n_valeurs, $x_entrees, $combi_presences = array()) {
    if ($n_valeurs == 1) {
        $combi_presences[] = $x_entrees;
        return array($combi_presences);
    }

    $combinaisons = array();

    for ($tiroir = 0; $tiroir <= $x_entrees; $tiroir++) {
        $combinaisons = array_merge($combinaisons, distributions_possibles2(
            $n_valeurs - 1,
            $x_entrees - $tiroir,
            array_merge($combi_presences, array($tiroir))));
    }
    global $x;
    global $distri;
    global $bdd;
    $distri[$x] = count($combinaisons);
    if($distri[$x-1] == 1){
        if(!empty($combinaisons)){
            foreach($combinaisons as $distrib){
                $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO distributions (ID, distribution, repartition, nb_solutions, reduction) VALUES (NULL, "'.implode($distrib).'", 0, 0, 0)');
                $req->execute();
            }
        }
        $combinaisons = [];
    }
    $x++;
    return $combinaisons;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `distributions` table started out empty?

Comment: Yes I empty it before I start the function